# Save JSON to SQLite

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am making an android app and have to save JSON to an SQLite database.
The app already has a function to get JSON and display this in a listview and a function to save data to a database. Now I want to combine those, but I am a little lost.

```
    public void get_data(String data)    {
    try {
        JSONArray data_array=new JSONArray(data);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < data_array.length() ; i++)
        {
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(data_array.get(i).toString());

            Courses add=new Courses();
            add.name = obj.getString("name");
            add.ects = obj.getString("ects");
            add.grade = obj.getString("grade");
            add.period = obj.getString("period");

            courses.add(add);



        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This loops through the JSON so I think this is where is should save to the database.

```
public boolean insertCourse(String course, int ects, int period, int grade) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(COURSE_COLUMN_COURSE, course);
    contentValues.put(COURSE_COLUMN_ECTS, ects);
    contentValues.put(COURSE_COLUMN_PERIOD, period);
    contentValues.put(COURSE_COLUMN_GRADE, grade);

    db.insert(COURSE_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}
```

This is in a DBHelper.class should be able to use this I think.

I was hoping to reuse the code which i used to save input fields to the database but no luck so far.

```
    else {
        if(dbHelper.insertCourse(courseEditText.getText().toString(),
                Integer.parseInt(ectsEditText.getText().toString()),
                Integer.parseInt(periodEditText.getText().toString()),
                Integer.parseInt(gradeEditText.getText().toString()))) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Course Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not Insert course", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to integrate both (if possible at all).
Thnx in advance

EDIT:
the logcat crash report:

```
04-09 17:45:37.204 12244-12244/com.stefspakman.progress2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.stefspakman.progress2, PID: 12244
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.stefspakman.progress2.ProgressDBHelper.insertCourse(java.lang.String, int, int, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.stefspakman.progress2.gradingActivity.get_data(gradingActivity.java:60)
                                                                           at com.stefspakman.progress2.Download_data$1.handleMessage(Download_data.java:58)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Call `insertCourse` method when you extract the data from JSON .

Comment: @PrerakSola I just tried ` String dbCourse = obj.getString("name");
                int dbects = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("ects"));
                int dbperiod = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("period"));
                int dbgrade = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("grade"));

                dbHelper.insertCourse(dbCourse,dbects,dbperiod,dbgrade );`, but the app crashes as soon as i open the activity.

Comment: Post the logcat of the crash in your question.

Comment: @PrerakSola added the Logcat above

Comment: @StefSpakman you have null, check the documentation official https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate your DBHelper class before using the insertCourse Method .

```
DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
helper.insertCourse(Course course);
```

Also , its better if you use your Model class object as paramater for database queries .

```
public boolean insertCourse(Courses courses) {
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

contentValues.put(COURSE_COLUMN_COURSE, courses.getCourse());
contentValues.put(COURSE_COLUMN_ECTS, courses.getEcts());
contentValues.put(COURSE_COLUMN_PERIOD, courses.getPeriod());
contentValues.put(COURSE_COLUMN_GRADE, courses.getGrade());

db.insert(COURSE_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
return true;
```

}

In this way you can save your data from JSON as

```
db.insert(courses);
```

Comment: I changed the `insertCourse` but now i get an error "cannot resolve 'getCourse()'"

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that your `ProgressDBHelper` is null, please make sure that you are creating an instance of `ProgressDBHelper` before calling its methods. Creating an instance is just calling `ProgressDBHelper dbHelper = new ProgressDBHelper()` and you have to call it before calling `dbHelper.insertCourse(...)`